# Loop through parent Div and change Div Children class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing some code where I count the number of Div children and then based on the loop iteration I want to have a new div class name, for example ".ClassName" + i. I am trying to do this with Jquery but it's not working for some reason.

```
<div class="Parent">

    <div class="Percentage">
    <pe:Percentage runat="server" />
    </div>

    <div class="Percentage">
    <pe:Percentage runat="server" />
    </div>

    <div class="Percentage">
    <pe:Percentage runat="server" />
    </div>

</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".Percentage").each(function(i, val) {
        alert(val.innerHTML);
        $("#Parent .Percentage").removeClass(".Percentage").addClass(".Percentage" + i); 
        alert(val.innerHTML);

    });

    //        var count = $('.Percentage').length;
    //        alert(count);
    //        percentageCount();


});
```

What would be a good way of doing this?

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/h5mhj/1/)**

```
$(".Percentage").each(function(i, val) {

    $(this).removeClass("Percentage").addClass("Percentage" + i);

});
```

You should not give dot while adding or removing class

removeClass(".Percentage") **should be removeClass("Percentage")**

addClass(".Percentage" + i); **should be addClass("Percentage" + i)**

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly! The live demo helped as well because I wanted to see what the new HTML looks like and your code makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove dot
2. Parent is a class name not an id
3. You don't need a foreach to do this

   $(".Parent .Percentage").removeClass("Percentage").addClass("Percentage" + i);

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            $(".Parent .Percentage").each(function(i,val)
            {
                $(this).removeClass('Percentage').addClass("Percentage"+i);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
$(".Percentage").each(function(i, val) {
        $(this).removeClass("Percentage").addClass("Percentage" + i); 
    });
```

(no "." when adding or removing a class, just the class name)

Even better for performance, use a classic `for` instead of `each`:

```
var $percentageElements = $(".Percentage");
for(var i = O; i< $percentageElements.length; i++){
 var $percentage = $percentageElements.eq(i);
 $percentage.removeClass("Percentage").addClass("Percentage" + i);
}
```

Comment: This will cause an error because Percentage is undefined. Its expecting a string not an object or variable.

Comment: What do you mean? There's no Percentage object in my answer. I'm pretty sure this would work.

Comment: Try using the Jquery removeClass function and in the parenthesis use Percentage and not "Percentage". It will say Percentage undefined because it sees it as a variable when its expecting a string to be provided.

Comment: Sure it will, but in my answer I used "Percentage" not Percentage alone :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first add the new class and then only remove the old class.
DEMO  at http://jsfiddle.net/KV7BZ/

Answer (score 0):

you may use `$(this)` instead of `$("#Parent .Percentage")` and remove `.` (dot) as you are already dealing with class.

so

```
$("#Parent .Percentage").removeClass(".Percentage").addClass(".Percentage" + i);
```

should be:

```
$(this).removeClass("Percentage").addClass("Percentage" + i);
```